# How to join multiple tables and group by and get top 2 from one table

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 tables: isps, offers and sponsors.

I have table statistics have the foreign key of these 3 tables.

I need to get all isps grouped by target, sponsor and offers but I want to get just the top 2 offers that have the top epc in every isp, target and sponsor.

```
Schema::create('isps', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('sponsors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
 
Schema::create('offers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('offer_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreignIdFor(Sponsor::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
 
Schema::create('statistics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->date('at')->nullable();
            $table->foreignIdFor(Isp::class)->nullable();
            $table->foreignIdFor(Sponsor::class)->nullable();
            $table->foreignIdFor(Offer::class)->nullable();

            $table->string('target')->default('NA');
            $table->unsignedInteger('clicks')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedDecimal('earns')->default(0);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is my function. It works but it gets all offers while I want to get the top 2 offers that have the top epc grouped by isps, target, sponsors and offers.

`epc=sum(statistics.earns)/ nullif(sum(statistics.clicks) group by isps, target and sponsors and offers`

```
$stats = Statistic::query()->where('at', '>=', now()->subMonth())->selectRaw('
                 statistics.sponsor_id as sponsar_id,
                 sponsors.name as sponsor_name,
                 statistics.target,
                 statistics.isp_id as isp_id,
                 isps.name as isp_name,
                 statistics.offer_id as offer_id,
                 offers.name as offer_name, coalesce(sum(statistics.earns)/ nullif(sum(statistics.clicks)::numeric, 0),0) as epc
                ')
        ->join('sponsors', 'sponsors.id', '=', 'statistics.sponsor_id')
        ->join('offers', 'offers.id', '=', 'statistics.offer_id')
        ->join('isps', 'isps.id', '=', 'statistics.isp_id')
        ->groupBy(
            'statistics.target', 'statistics.isp_id', 'isps.name', 'statistics.sponsor_id',
            'sponsors.name', 'statistics.offer_id', 'offers.name')
        ->getQuery()
        ->get();

    if ($stats->isEmpty()) {
        return [];
    }

    return $stats->transform(fn($row) => [
        'isp' => $row->isp_name,
        'target' => $row->target,
        'sponsor' => $row->sponsor_name,
        'offer' => $row->offer_name,
        'epc' => $row->epc,
    ])->toArray();
```

| isp | target | sponsor | offers | epc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hotmail | spam | S1 | OF1 | 10 |
| hotmail | spam | S1 | OF12 | 5 |
| hotmail | spam | S2 | OF6 | 12 |
| hotmail | spam | S2 | OF12 | 6 |
| gmail | inbox | S1 | OF16 | 9 |
| gmail | inbox | S1 | OF5 | 3 |
| gmail | inbox | S2 | OF5 | 12 |
| gmail | inbox | S2 | OF5 | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

you can just add an `orderBy('')` clause to sort as you deem fit followed by `->take(2)` to select only two items

Comment: when i add orderBy('') take(2) they return just 2 isps
 but i want to get all isps and all target and  all sponsor and take just top 2 offers by epc
i hope you understand me

Comment: in this case then you need to modify orderBy to orderBy('epc', 'DESC') so that sorting will happen based on the epc value